# Maximum number of allowed versions changes for SSM Parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, ssm

I have an SSM parameter created which will need a frequent update to it (almost 20 times a min). The SSM put_parameter API says it can return some error in case it exceeds the max limit versions.

ParameterMaxVersionLimitExceeded
The parameter exceeded the maximum number of allowed versions.

HTTP Status Code: 400

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/APIReference/API_PutParameter.html

So my question is what is the maximum allowed version changes we can make and is that limit configurable?

official documentation reference will be highly helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your question, there is a limit for storing the 100 past values for the parameter.
For more information, you can go through the below link:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html#limits_ssm

According to AWS Support, 100 is the soft AND hard limit as of March 2022:

> Our service team has got back to us and has informed us that unfortunately 100 is the hard limit for this specific service.
>
> They've determined that a parameter can have max 100 versions at a given time. Parameter Store rotates the history of the parameter, when version 101 is created, the oldest version is deleted. This should happen automatically. If you're seeing `ParameterMaxVersionLimitExceeded`, you may have a label associated with the oldest version. You may need to move the label to another version, to be able to overwrite the parameter.